# Eclipse global preferences

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clone workspace in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848767/clone-workspace-in-eclipse)

I started a new workspace a couple of weeks ago, and configured eclipse ( Window -> Preferences ). I configured alot of stuff, hotkeys and so on.

Now I have started a new Workspace, but none of the old settings are available. 
Is there a way to configure global preferences for eclipse?

I know I can export/import preferences but I have some doubts if that actually takes all of the preferences. Previous experience has told me no, plus it is inconvient as one change in one workspace won't get updated in another and you have this constant non-synchronized properties.

Thank you !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a look at the following plugin : https://github.com/alfsch/workspacemechanic

It's a plugin developed by google which lets you store your preferences and apply them to any workspace automatically.

If you store it in your dropbox (or any other shared storage), you'll be able to share you preferences between all your computers and even between all your team members.

It's the best and most reliable solution for your problem.

Comment: You know if this supports plugin settings and such as well ?

Comment: Yes, since almost everything in eclipse is a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

No, that´s not possible. All settings are done per workspace.