# Rad 7.5.4 workspace migration?

Tags: ide, clearcase, ibm-rad

Let me explain my situation:

- I have IBM RAD 7.5.4 and IBM ClearCase as my Version control software.
- for my workspace, I import lot of projects ; some of them I import them into my local workspace and some are team projects, all I do is import one of the `.psf` files and am good to go.

If i were to migrate to a different PC, is there any way to copy the entire workspace, so that from the moment I set it up, I should be able to work

These projects contain lot of jars and ears: is there any way to put them all into a single ear?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to exporting an eclipse workspace is at least to version in ClearCase the:

- `.project`
- `.classpath`
- `settings/`

(as I describe in "[`.classpath` and `.project` - check into version control or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309)")

That is, provided you can use **relative paths** in your settings.

For a full Eclipse workspace clone, you might consider "[Clone workspace in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385298/6309)", with plugin like [workspacemechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/).