# automate preferences for projects in RAD 7.5.4

Tags: ide, clearcase, rad

i have a scenario where I have multiple projects, which I have to import projects as team project "`psf`" file (every now and then).

The thing is we have to configure the preferences again, like adding one "jar",adding the "JRE library" and server library again...

Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

If your eclipse project metadata (mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079579/6309)) are versioned at the same level than your source in ClearCase, then you should be to:

- update a snapshot view with the (one or many) projects
- import that project into your workspace

[image: Import existing project]

If that is working (meaning you find all your jar, and JRE settings back after importing one project from the sources), *then* you can try importing a PSF.

Importing a ["Project Set File" (psf)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF), means referencing the VCS (see "[Structure of a Project Set File](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Project_set_file)"), that is your ClearCase sources in your case.
So first try importing a project, then the psf.

Comment: Where in the file architecture can I find the PSF file?  I think this might be the answer to a question I recently asked.

Comment: @Zibbobz good question, but I don't have the answer right now.