# Clone Java local workspace

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, workspace

I'm working on a Java application created from multiple Eclipse plugins. The application uses a local workspace. When the user clicks on a specific button I want to clone the application workspace on a remote server programmatically.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: remote server means what ? you want to use FTP for file cloning.

Comment: for the first step just need cloning workspace in another location. I heard  about Eclipse Resource API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Platform API to get to the local workspace. Theoretically, once you get that you can zip it and do whatever you need to do.

```
Platform.getInstanceLocation();
```

I say theoretically because files can be **located outside of the workspace** e.g. which is the case when you use git. You have to craft what you want to export and import.

See this question for additional hints and tips [1]

[1] [How to Clone an Eclipse Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848767/how-to-clone-an-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: Okay but as I see `Platform.getInstanceLocation();` return an 
`org.eclipse.osgi.service.datalocation.Location`. so how can I manipulate it to  get projects, files ...

Comment: Please update the question with this new information then I will answer that as well.